# New node in firebase DB each time the user logs in

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am creating the testing/examining app in React. The questions are predefined and stored in firebase database in one node and I would like to store the undertaken tests in another node. But I would like the new subnode to be added for every new exam attempt.

Unfortunately as for now the results are replaced.

I need the structure like this:

```
 "answers": {
    "0": {
      "user": "Mr X",
      "testDone": true,
      "result": 3,
      "questions": {
        "0": {
          "content": "How much is 2 x 2?",
          "selectedAnswer": "A",
          "correctAnswer": "A"
        },
        "1": {
          "content": "How much is 2 + 2?",
          "selectedAnswer": "B",
          "correctAnswer": "B"
        },
        "2": {
          "content": "How much is 2 / 2?",
          "selectedAnswer": "C",
          "correctAnswer": "C"
        }
      }
    },
    "1": {
      "user": "Mr Y",
      "testDone": true,
      "result": 1,
      "questions": {
        "0": {
          "content": "How much is 2 x 2?",
          "selectedAnswer": "A",
          "correctAnswer": "A"
        },
        "1": {
          "content": "How much is 2 + 2?",
          "selectedAnswer": "C",
          "correctAnswer": "B"
        },
        "2": {
          "content": "How much is 2 / 2?",
          "selectedAnswer": "B",
          "correctAnswer": "C"
        }
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "user": "Mr Z",
      "testDone": true,
      "result": 2,
      "questions": {
        "0": {
          "content": "How much is 2 x 2?",
          "selectedAnswer": "A",
          "correctAnswer": "A"
        },
        "1": {
          "content": "How much is 2 + 2?",
          "selectedAnswer": "B",
          "correctAnswer": "B"
        },
        "2": {
          "content": "How much is 2 / 2?",
          "selectedAnswer": "A",
          "correctAnswer": "C"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the future I would like also to prevent the users from undertaking exam more than one time. So I would need to either check during the authentication if particular username is already present in answers object or predefine answers object and authenticate only users that are inside this object and have the value of property testDone set to false.

So my question is how can I enforce the firebase to add new node for new exam attempt and then synchronize the app states with the particular subnodes (each time different subnodes will be synchronized).

Comment: What is your code that doesn't work the way you expect?  Please edit your question to be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a node just for test results and each time a user takes the test, their results are added to that node using a unique ID for each new result. This way they will not overwrite previously saved results and you can bind the users ID to the result too.

```
//Database reference
var firebaseDb = firebase.database().ref.child("completed_tests");

//example score from a test
var usersScore = 9;

//Creating a new reference with a newly generated key, unique to this node.
var resultsRef = firebaseDb.push();

//Getting the unique key so we can use it to save data to it.
var newId = resultsRef.key;

//Adding data to the node we created above, inside the "completed_tests" node.
firebaseDb.child(newId).child("grade").set(userScore);
```

The database could look something like this example.

```
    {
    "root": {
        "completed_tests": {
            "uniqueTestId_12345": {
                "Which_test": "test_1",
                "userId": "1234_uid_of_test_taker",
                "grade": 9
            },
            "uniqueTestId_23456": {
                "grade": 5
            },
            "uniqueTestId_34567": {
                "grade": 7
            }
        },
        "tests": {
            "test_1": {
                "Q1": "Who am I?",
                "Q2": "..."
            },
            "test_2": {
                "Q1": "Who are You?",
                "Q2": "..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above is a simple example of saving data with a unique ID using JavaScript. You could obviously save more data to the node, maybe individual answers, scores, timestamp, uid, a pointer back to the original test etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer. Now my componentDidMount() function looks as follows:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var firebaseDb = firebaseApp.database().ref("completed_tests");
    var resultsRef = firebaseDb.push();
    var newId = resultsRef.key;
    this.ref = fbase.syncState("/completed_tests/" + newId + "/user/", {
      context: this,
      asArray: true,
      state: "user"
    });
    this.ref = fbase.syncState("/completed_tests/" + newId + "/answers/", {
      context: this,
      asArray: true,
      state: "answers"
    });
    this.ref = fbase.syncState("/completed_tests/" + newId + "/result/", {
      context: this,
      asArray: true,
      state: "result"
    });
  }
```

It works nice, but there is one more thing I would like to improve. Now each of the node references consists of strange string of characters. I would prefer to have the node with the name same as login (email address) but of course with replaced "." to any sign allowed by firabase (i.e. "_"). For this reason I changed my authentication function to the following:

```
  authenticate = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    firebaseApp
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          loggedIn: 1,
          user: this.state.email
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("Unable to authenticate");
      });
    firebaseApp
      .database()
      .ref("/users/")
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        for (var key in snapshot.val()) {
          if (this.state.email.replace(".", "_") === key) {
            this.setState({
              loggedIn: 2
            });
            console.log("you have already filled the test");
          } else {
            console.log("it's first time you arte taking this test");
          }
        }
      });
  };
```

The value of loggedIn state is used to control the content to be displayed, so I can prevent users form taking the test more than one time. But now I would like to add the new node (which be the user login) and send all the other objects into it. Adding this node is not a problem, but I cannot get through binding states with this new node. If I put it in authenticate function it doesn't work because authentication comes after the binding code is added.
Binding inside componentDidMount() also does not work, because value of state connected to login is changed after componentDidMount() function is called.

Is there any way to overcome that?